# Apache server status interpretation?what does ::1 mean?

Tags: apache, ip

I enabled mod_status of Apache to monitor the server, but I don't know why some of the rows does not have an ip address, what dose '::1' mean?

```
Slot    Client  VHost   Request

273.08  ::1 vps66215.vps.li.us  OPTIONS * HTTP/1.0
```

Comment: I think it just means that the client is xserver's first window/session (if it is linux) where your browser is currently opened.

Comment: ::1 in just shortcut meaning the server itself - same thing as if you see 127.0.0.1 - there are other abbreviations for "me, myself and I"